# Examples of null homologous spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can anyone give some nice and simple examples of spaces that are null homologous? I know this is much of a question but much appreciate any feedback/ references. Thank you!

Comment: These spaces are called "acyclic". Non-contractible examples are for example [homology spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) from which you remove a point. I think [this paper](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~farjoun/acyclic%20spaces.pdf) is a standard reference.

Comment: I've always sort of liked the example of the group $G = \langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \mid x_{i+1} x_i x_{i+1}^{-1} = x_i^2, \, i \in \mathbb{Z}/4 \rangle$.  This is a particularly small acyclic group, so its classifying space $BG$ is acyclic.